# How to use figures as inline images?

Tags: graphics, svg

I have converted SVG images into pdf_tex usable format using inkscape and used it in my document as follows:

```
% \begin{figure}[h]
%     \def\svgscale{0.02}
%     \input{phone.pdf_tex}
% \end{figure}
```

I want to use the image inline with some text (Like - " this is an apple #" where '#' = a little image of an apple) .
I'm not able to do it. I'm new to LaTeX and I'm confused. Probably using it in some other file and using it as a package in .tex file might help, but again, I have no idea how that works.

Comment: If you use it inside a float environment like figure, it will end up where LaTeX thinks it looks good, not where you pasted the code. Try without the figure environment. For proper scaling, you may also want to set `\svgscale` to something like the line height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the image inline by simply removing `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`. It you don't want to change the `\svgwidth` for the whole document, you can wrap it into a group ussing `{...}`.

```
\documentclass{book}%

\usepackage{graphicx}   

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\svgwidth{2cm}
\input{name.pdf_tex}
\caption{sdj}
\end{figure}

This is an apple {\def\svgwidth{2cm}\input{name.pdf_tex}} and more text


\end{document}
```